# How do you make viewport width different on mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is there a way you can make the viewpoint width on mobile 700 and keep the 1080 on desktop

eg:
meta name="viewport" content="width=700" (for mobile only)

meta name="viewport" content="width=1080"(for desktop only)

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=700">
```

… because desktop browsers ignore viewport instructions anyway.

Meta viewport exists because when smartphones were first introduced nobody had designed websites for them. Nobody would have been able to sell a smartphone if every website broke as a result so they defaulted to doing weird zooming tricks and provided *viewport* settings so that if someone did account for smartphones when designing their site they wouldn't be stuck with inappropriate zooming.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't specify a width in your viewport settings. It is there in case you already have a website from the turn of the century with a fixed width design and you need modern, small screen devices to be able to cope with it.

In most cases

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

… is optimal along with CSS that makes use of media queries to make the design properly responsible.

---

If you really want to set the width based on the device then you'll probably have to resort to detecting the screen size with JavaScript, setting that in a cookie, then triggering a reload.

Then, if the cookie is present, set the meta tag with server side code and don't output the JS that set the cookie and reloaded the page.

I don't recommend that approach.